# To stop a Background Music from 1 activity to another using a checkbox?

Tags: java, android

My Main Activity has a background music, and I want to stop it whenever I can, through a checkbox. I have the codes already in order to set the background music into the Main activity, and it works perfect. The problem is that I want to stop a specific song from another activity using a CheckBox. I configured the checkbox, however, it does not work. Somehelp is really appreciated.

PD: The comunication between these two activities work well. It is the checkbox that does not work

Here are my codes used.

*MainActivity.java*

`

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    MediaPlayer bkgrdmsc;
    private int lmusic_checked = SettingsActivity.music_checked;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

if (lmusic_checked == 0){
        bkgrdmsc = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.backgroundmusic);
        bkgrdmsc.setLooping(true);
        bkgrdmsc.start();

    }
 @Override
protected void onPause() {
    if (lmusic_checked == 0){
        bkgrdmsc.release();
    }
    SettingsActivity.music_checked =0;
    super.onPause();
    bkgrdmsc.release();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    //inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if this is present
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        Intent s_intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
        startActivity(s_intent);
        return true;
    }
    else if (id == R.id.logo_home){
        Intent t_intent = new Intent(this, Twitter.class);
        startActivity(t_intent);
        return true;
    }


    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}
```

*activity_settings.xml*

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="271dp"
        android:layout_height="77dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/c_general"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
        android:textSize="26dp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/turn_on_music"
        android:id="@+id/CheckBox"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:checked="false"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:textColor="#000000" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

*SettingsActivity.java*

```
package com.example.json.publicomidas;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;




public class SettingsActivity extends Activity {

public static int music_checked= 0;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.action_settings);

    music_off();
}
public void music_off(){
    CheckBox checkBox1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.CheckBox);
    checkBox1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (buttonView.isChecked()) {

                music_checked = 1;
            } else {
                music_checked = 0;
            }
        }
    });

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    //inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if this is present
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_settings, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.home) {
        Intent s_intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(s_intent);

        return true;

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Man, you should not do it this way... You cannot make two activities communicate each other with a static field :) When you change the value of `music_checked` in `SetttingsActivity` this changes nothing in the `MainActivity`.

My advice is to create a `Service` that runs the music. Both the activities should properly bind to the service and manipulate the music playback.

**Update1**

The communication you have implemented using this static field works only in one direction. You cannot stop the music by changing the `music_checked` property. It is a property of the `SettingsActivity` class and the `MainActivity` instance knows nothing about its state.

The proper way to implement this is using a `Service` that plays the music. It is not correct to play the music from an `Activity` if you want the playback to continue after the activity is paused/stoped. Create a [bound service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) and bind each activity to the service in their `onResume` or `onStart` method (and unbind in `onPause`/`onStop`). By binding to the service you receive an object that exposes some API (you have to define this API and create the object according to the functionality you want to have). Using this API you can control the service from both the activities.

I'll advise you to read a bit more about activities and services in android and their lifecycle.

Comment: Kiril, I used the static field  on ```music_checked = 0;``` Why this, because I want to control when the music is play or not, and even if I do not want the music to play. I set ```music_checked= 1;```

Comment: @Jason, take a look at my updated answer please. Don't hesitate to ask if there is something unclear :)

Comment: @Jason, if my answer helped you, may I ask you to accept it as the correct one :)

Comment: I tried to put the same codes on MainActivity. I mean, I put the CheckBox in MainActivity , and it still doesn't working. I want another way in instead of using a ```Service```

Comment: You cannot achieve communication between android components using a static member. There is now mechanism that notifies the activity that the static field has changed. You should use ```Intent``` objects to communicate between activities. I strongly recommend the use of the approach I described above.

Comment: @Jason, is there any update about your question? If you think my answer helped you, may I ask you to accept it as the correct one? :)